# Why is the IP address lookup in /etc/hosts only sometimes work?

Tags: hosts, etc

The '/etc/hosts' file in a Linux laptop (with LAN IP 172.17.37.21) by default contains :

```
127.0.1.1 Acer-Aspire-6930G
```

When I want to reach this laptop wirelessly from a smartphone or a PC using an FTP client, then setting the FTP server (vsftpd) as 127.0.1.1, Acer-Aspire-6930G, or Acer-Aspire-6930G.local sometimes work, but at other times doesn't work. Why is this?

In my modem/router I can set the LAN IP address to always be the same for the MAC address of the laptop, so that 172.17.37.21 can always be used as the FTP server address but, unfortunately, the modem/router at my nephew's laptop site doesn't has this setting. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you describe exactly how you access the laptop, and what you mean by "it doesn't work"? Also, how do smartphone and PC translate the name *Acer-Aspire-6930G* to an IP address? Finally, have you checked the vsftpd logs?

Comment: Adding an entry to `/etc/hosts` affects hostname lookups from _that_ computer, not from other computers on your network (e.g., smart phones or PCs)

Comment: @Andy Dalton: You're absolutely right.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question: Is there a generic way to reach the laptop wirelessly from a smartphone or PC on the same LAN using an FTP client on the smartphone and PC and an vsftpd on the laptop WITHOUT referring to the LAN IP address of the laptop (i.e. FTP server) in these clients?

Comment: Yes, if you have a DHCP and DNS server in your network. Otherwise, no.